# confusion in how backtracking works given query with member predicate

Tags: prolog

Suppose i invoke the query `member(a, [c,b,a,y])`, the output is -

```
true ;
false.
```

How come we have "another solution"? Why we dont finish at `true.`?

Here's the trace:

```
%% [trace]  ?- member(a,[c,b,a,y]).
%%    Call: (6) member(a, [c, b, a, y]) ?
%%    Call: (7) member(a, [b, a, y]) ?
%%    Call: (8) member(a, [a, y]) ?
%%    Exit: (8) member(a, [a, y]) ?
%%    Exit: (7) member(a, [b, a, y]) ?
%%    Exit: (6) member(a, [c, b, a, y]) ?
%% true ;
%%    Redo: (8) member(a, [a, y]) ?
%%    Call: (9) member(a, [y]) ?
%%    Call: (10) member(a, []) ?
%%    Fail: (10) member(a, []) ?
%%    Fail: (9) member(a, [y]) ?
%%    Fail: (8) member(a, [a, y]) ?
%%    Fail: (7) member(a, [b, a, y]) ?
%%    Fail: (6) member(a, [c, b, a, y]) ?
%% false.
```

I don't understand how can we backtrack to (8) and why?

---

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[Y|T]) :- member(X,T).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's re-write it as the nearly-equivalent one-liner,

```
membr(X,[A|B]):- ( X = A ; membr(X,B) ).
```

Tracing *it* can be a bit clearer:

```
[trace] 5 ?- trace, membr(a, [c,b,a,y]).         X=a
   Call: (8) membr(a, [c, b, a, y]) ? creep        [A8|B8]=[c,b,a,y]
   Call:  (9) a=c ? creep                            X=A8 ?
   Fail:  (9) a=c ? creep                            false
   Redo: (8) membr(a, [c, b, a, y]) ? creep        membr(X,B8) ?
   Call:  (9) membr(a, [b, a, y]) ? creep            [A9|B9]=B8
   Call:   (10) a=b ? creep                            X=A9 ?
   Fail:   (10) a=b ? creep                            false
   Redo:  (9) membr(a, [b, a, y]) ? creep            membr(X,B9) ?
   Call:   (10) membr(a, [a, y]) ? creep               [A10|B10]=B9
   Call:    (11) a=a ? creep                             X=A10 ?
   Exit:    (11) a=a ? creep                             true
   Exit:   (10) membr(a, [a, y]) ? creep               success!
   Exit:  (9) membr(a, [b, a, y]) ? creep            success!
   Exit: (8) membr(a, [c, b, a, y]) ? creep        success!
true ;
   Redo:   (10) membr(a, [a, y]) ? creep               membr(X,B10) ?
   Call:    (11) membr(a, [y]) ? creep                   [A11|B11]=B10
   Call:     (12) a=y ? creep                              X=A11 ?
   Fail:     (12) a=y ? creep                              .........
   Redo:    (11) membr(a, [y]) ? creep                     .........
   Call:     (12) membr(a, []) ? creep
   Fail:     (12) membr(a, []) ? creep
   Fail:    (11) membr(a, [y]) ? creep
   Fail:   (10) membr(a, [a, y]) ? creep
   Fail:  (9) membr(a, [b, a, y]) ? creep
   Fail: (8) membr(a, [c, b, a, y]) ? creep
false.
```

There's clearly a choice point waiting, after the first success is reached:

```
(10) membr(X,[A|B]):- ( X = A ; membr(X,B) ).
```

and after the success is reported, with all the frames still there on the stack, the top -- 10th -- frame is retried from the point where it has stopped, having succeeded:

```
(10) membr(X,[A|B]):- ( X = A ; membr(X,B) ).
```

The chain of exits is provisional: we've only traced back up the stack in order to be able to report the found value, as its bits and pieces are stored in the frames leading to the successful 11th frame (with `X=a, A10=a, X=A10`). The frames were not eliminated, for if they were, we'd only ever could report only the one first found value. But Prolog wants to report *all* of them.

Comment: It's a one-liner, yes. But still there should be round brackets around the `(;)/2`.

Comment: `listing(membr)`